# How to show content based on url parameter via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

**[Update] code I have edited**

First, the plain HTML :

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript_accord.php/option/coke/">coke</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript_accord.php/option/bubble-tea/">buble-tea</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript_accord.php/option/milk/">milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

Second, link page (javascript_accord.php) contain javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
var option = 'coke';
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
option = url[3];
showDiv(option);
});

    function showDiv(option) {
$('.boxes').hide();
$('#' + option).show();

   }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="boxes" id="coke">Coke is awesome!</div>
    <div class="boxes" id="bubble-tea">Bubble tea is da bomb!</div>
    <div class="boxes" id="milk">Milk is healthy!</div>
    <p>
I change my mind:
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('coke')">Coke</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('bubble-tea')">Bubble Tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('milk')">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
   </p>
   <a href="http://localhost/selectaccord.php">Back to main page</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

---

I found some tutorial about 'show/hide' content based on URL parameter via JavaScript. 
But I stuck when I change a part of the JavaScript code.

Here are the code that I learned from the tutorial.
First page contain some links to other page:

```
If you had to choose a drink, what would you choose:
<a href="/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option=coke" 
<a href="/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option=bubble-tea"
<a href="/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option=milk
```

And here is the code contain in linking page (`/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html`) :

```
<div class="boxes" id="coke">Coke is awesome!</div>
<div class="boxes" id="bubble-tea">Bubble tea is da bomb!</div>
<div class="boxes" id="milk">Milk is healthy!</div>
<p>
I change my mind:
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('coke')">Coke</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('bubble-tea')">Bubble Tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('milk')">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
<a href="/demo/demo.html">Back to main page</a>
```

And the javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var option = 'coke';
    var url = window.location.href;
    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    showDiv(option);
});
function showDiv(option) {
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $('#' + option).show();
}
</script>
```

It works greatly, but when I try to change the link page from

```
href="/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option=coke"
```

into something like this :

```
href="/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html/option/coke"
```

And change the url variable in javascript from

```
var url = window.location.href;
option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
```

to

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
option = url[3];
```

And all content in

```
<div class="boxes" id="...">
```

appear.

It supposed to be only selected one will appear. I have tried

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
option = url[3];
```

in simple JavaScript to check whether it will catch the right or value or not. And it does return the right value (coke, milk, bubble-tea).

So, what went wrong? 
I hope somebody understand this problem and help.

Comment: do you see some error in javascript console on page load? can you share your code? you can use jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Nakul I'm not sure how to use jsfiddle.net but here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/WLTSd/1/

Comment: can you paste the full url that you see on link(javascript) page?

Comment: here is the full url http://localhost/javascript_accord.php/option/coke

Comment: before $('#' + option).show(); add this statement and see in your console in firefox or chrome. console.log(option, $('#' + option)); You should see the option and corrosponding div. This will help you in debugging.

Comment: There is an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.3.2.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined coke:24 What does this mean?

Comment: I don't really know.... but I see some similar problem after googling , it seem a bug on Jquery.

Comment: I suggest on your script page, try to see if you can target your boxes using simple command in console like $('#coke') see if the div shows up. Also pay attention to script errors if any.

Comment: Yes, the div shows up : "<div class="boxes" id="coke">Coke is awesome!</div>" And the error is :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.3.2.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined coke:24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path to jquery is wrong. Can you please check if jquery library is loading?

jquery will be loaded from javascript_accord.php/option/coke/development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js 
Please make the path to library absolute. That should do :)

Comment: Oh my gosh :D Yeah, you're absolutely right. Now, all works fine. Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that window.location will return the full URL of the page, so you're not just working with the `/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html/option/coke` part.

I'd simply change the regular expression instead to replace the `=` with a `/`, like so:

`option = url.match(/option\/(.*)/)[1];`

Comment: I tried as you said but it did not work. If I set the URL to "/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option/coke" then the "option=url.match(/option\/(.*)/)[1]" will work. I tried : "option=url.match(/\/option\/(.*)/)[1]" also not working.

Comment: @TaniaRida Can you edit the question to include the code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

`"/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html/option/coke".split('/')[3]` will return option and not coke

there are 5 entries in the array, because there is an empty string before the first '/':
"",
"demo",
"demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html",
"option" and
"coke"

Comment: Yes, sorry. Actually I didnt use this link : "/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html/option/coke". I have updated my question and included the code I have now

Comment: You can also try: url = "/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html/option/coke";
var results = url.split('/');
var option = results[results.length-1];